# DataSource cannot be cast to com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to create a context.xml out of this code:

```
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass( "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver     
        cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.38.28.77/MyDB" );   
        cpds.setUser("sa");                                  
        cpds.setPassword("password");   
        cpds.setMaxStatements( 180 );
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
    return cpds.getConnection();
```

I mean, to convert this hard-coded setting into context.xml like:

```
        <Resource name="jdbc/MyDBHrd" 
         driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
         maxPoolSize="100"
         minPoolSize="15"
         acquireIncrement="1"
         auth="Container"
         maxStatements="50"
         idleConnectionTestPeriod="3600"
         testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
         automaticTestTable="connection_test"
         maxIdleTime="21600"
         factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
         type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
         jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.114.130/MyDB"
         user="sa" password="password" />
```

However this context.xml when used:

```
    InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
    String jndiName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDBHrd";
    // Look up our data source
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = (ComboPooledDataSource) cxt.lookup(jndiName);
```

Throws:

```
ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DataSource cannot be cast to com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the data source as of the plain vanilla type, not that Combo thing. You're asking Tomcat to make a data source, it won't make one of those for you. If you need to wrap the plain data source in one of those, do that in Java.